# rss feed not displaying

Tags: php, xml, rss

I'm trying to create a rss feed that displays all my news.
So far the code seems to be half way there because if I view page source all the content is there but nothing is showing up on the actual page.

Here is my code rss.php

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
header("Content-type: text/xml");

include("config.php");
global $NEWS;
$str = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>';
$str.= '<rss version="2.0">';
$str.='<channel>';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $NEWS";

$result = mysql_query($sql) or die ($sql."".mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)){
    $str.= '<item>';
    $str.=' <a href="'.getSEOLink(13).'&article='.$row->id.'">';
    $str.= '<title>'.$row->title.'</title></a>'; 
    $str.= '<description><![CDATA['.$row->content. ']]></description>';
    $str.= '</item>';
}

$str .='</channel>';
$str .='</rss>';
echo $str;
?>
```

Comment: Would you mind posting the url to the feed? That will be easier to debug!

Comment: at the moment it's on my localhost

Answer (score 0):

Why not make use of [`asXML`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.asxml.php) of [`SimpleXMLElement`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php) ?

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
include("config.php");
global $NEWS;

$str='<channel>';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $NEWS";

$result = mysql_query($sql) or die ($sql."".mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)){
    $str.= '<item>';
    $str.=' <a href="'.getSEOLink(13).'&article='.$row->id.'">';
    $str.= '<title>'.$row->title.'</title></a>';
    $str.= '<description><![CDATA['.$row->content. ']]></description>';
    $str.= '</item>';
}

$str .='</channel>';

$xml=new SimpleXMLElement($str);
echo $xml->asXML();
```

Comment: Is there another way I can show you. When I put it in here it tells me that it's to long

Comment: I did some stuff now i only have this error. `Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): Entity: line 1: parser error : EntityRef: expecting ';' in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/baking/site/rss.php on line 55`

Answer (score 0):

You are apparently generating valid XML (thus your browser is not complaining) but not valid RSS (thus feed readers won't be able to read your stuff). For instance, `<a>` is not a valid RSS tag and definitively not a child of `<item>`.

Copy the *generated* XML (not the PHP source code) and validate it with your favourite RSS validator (e.g. [W3C Feed Validation Service](http://validator.w3.org/feed/)).